# Notification/Hook on document/window change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to write a browser extension that will do something when certain events happen and I am wondering if there is such an API (Firefox or Chrome) already.

I am mostly interested in DOM changes and window changes.

Let's consider this example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addContentToDocument(content){
        document.cookie = "debug=true"; //<--- Notify

        if(content != null){
            document.write(content); //<--- Notify
        };
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="addContentToDocument('Say cheese')">
<h3>My Content</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

So in this simple example I would be interested in 2 events: document.cookie alteration and document.write method call. I want to be notified in my extension when these things happen.
Not if these statements are present in the available javascript context, but if they are actually being executed.

I tried to search for an API in Firefox extensions and Chrome extensions but couldn't find anything useful.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**: Other methods I would be interested are the call of **eval()** method and **localStorage** modifications

Answer (score 1):

Current Firefox (and Chrome, with the `webkit` prefix) supports [`Mutation Observers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_Mutation_Observers). I don't think you can trap cookie changes with that, but you can definitely trap changes made to the DOM (whether or not made with `document.write`).

Example from the Mozilla docs:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true }

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: what about calls to modifying localStorage? or the call of eval() methods?

Comment: I actually never used those methods, I only know they exist. But I believe they are only for DOM mutations. For `eval`, you may override it with something like `var originalEval = eval; eval = function(){}`. You can do something similar with localStorage methods, too.

Comment: For localstorage you could just use the events emitted to the window object.  Something like: `window.addEventListener("storage", function() { console.log('storage'); }, false);` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor changes to a Document open in a tab/window, then MutationObservers are the way to do it. If you want to monitor methods called in pure JS, you'll need to look into the JSEngine apis for Spidermonkey in particular the apis arou nd profiling & tracing:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_User_Guide#Tracing_and_Profiling